# Trying to get function to loop with window.onload but isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, loops

I have this JavaScript/jQuery animation function going here and I want it to loop for every `3000` using `window.onload = function(){}`, but for some reason it's not working. I think it *could* by syntax/foundational errors as I am new to javascript, but if I should use a different method please tell me. Here's my code:

```
function animTile(){
    $(".main-content").delay(3000).animate({
        top: "100%"
    });

    $(".secondary-content").delay(3000).animate({
        top: "0"
    });
}

window.onload = function(){
    animTile(); setInterval(animTile, 3000);
}
```

## Edit:

Maybe this could also help. Here's my CSS code:

```
    #wrap {
        display: block;
        height: 328px;
        width: 568px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #wrap .main-content {
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0%;
    }

    #wrap .secondary-content {
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: You were right. Must use setTimeout

Comment: Hey you know it's actually your animTile function that's wrong.

Comment: Really? How so? And yeah, I tried your new way.

Comment: You need to reset the heights back after the first interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
 function animTile(){
$(".main-content").delay(3000).animate({
    top: "100%"
});

$(".secondary-content").delay(3000).animate({
    top: "0"
});
 animTileTwo();
}

function animTileTwo(){
$(".main-content").delay(3000).animate({
    top: "0"
});

$(".secondary-content").delay(3000).animate({
    top: "100%"
});
}


  window.onload=function(){
     setInterval("animTile()", 3000);
 }
```

Comment: no it doesn't.  it is actually preferable to pass by reference, as the OP was already doing

Comment: Oh, I just thought I'd inlcude for the heck of it that the `100%` should be `-100%`, just for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function animTile(){
$(".main-content").animate({
    top: "100%"
}, 1000);

$(".secondary-content").animate({
    top: "0"
}, 1000);
setTimeout('animTile()', 3000);
}

window.onload = function(){
animTile();
}
```

Comment: Hmm ':~\ No that still doesn't work. It only animates it once. But that does seem like it should work. Should I use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`?

Comment: No, that doesn't work. I don't know why though, that also seems logical. Hey guys, it might not help, but it could so I added by CSS also.

Comment: Well this is a real pain. Still not working! Should I try `window.onload = animTile()` or does it have to call an undefined function which calls the latter function?

Comment: I thought the time was already added in `setTimeout('animTile()', 3000);`

Comment: No, the time for the animation to run. in my case its 1000

Answer (score 0):

Why you used the 'delay' function? What do you want?
And you said you want some loop animation, but in your code, I only found one status for each element. I mean, if you want to have a loop animation, you should set some property to value A and later set it to value B, and later set it back to value A... that's a loop.

So, I guess you want set the 'top' property to '100%', and 3000 ms later, set it to 0, and 3000 ms later, set it to '100%'. Is that right?

If that is what you want, try these code:

```
    function toggle() {
        var elem = $('#id');
        if (elem.css('top') == '700px') {
            elem.animate({
                top: "0"
            });
        } else {
            elem.animate({
                top: "700px"
            });
        }
    }
    toggle();
    setInterval(toggle, 3000);
```